# Surjectivity of Lie group covering map

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to solve Chapter's 3 exercise 11 in the "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and Representations" Brian C. Hall's book. It reads as:

> If $\tilde{G}$ is a universal cover of a connected Lie group $G$ with
>   projection map $\Phi$, show that $\Phi$ maps $\tilde{G}$ onto $G$.

It looks like it has an easy and elegant proof but I am not arriving to it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn’t surjectivity in the definition of covering map?

Comment: I think not. The definition in this book says that $\Phi$ from $\tilde{G}$ to $G$ is only a Lie group homomorphism (such that the associated Lie Algebra homomorphism is a Lie Algebra isomorphism).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is open in a neighborhood of the identity (by inverse theorem, because is the identity at the level of its Lie algebra), and it is also a group homomorphism, so, its image  is an open connected subgroup containing the identity. This implies that the image is the connected component in the identity

Comment: I hope you'll consider this proof  "easy and elegant" as required :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have not seen the notification. It is indeed great! However, I am not sure how do you use the inverse theorem. Shall I use that since $\Phi$ is also a smooth map, then it maps any open set in $\tilde{G}$ to an open set in $G$?

Comment: The differential of the map, at the identity, is an isomorphism.